# Используя Selenium в headless режиме пропадает авторизация

Tags: python, selenium, headless

Использую следующие аргументы:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9292")
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=selenium") 
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
```

Перед использованием "headless" предварительно авторизовался на сайте, без него все работает нормально, но стоит мне включить этот режим, то авторизация пропадает (проверяю через driver.save_screenshot). В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: проблема в том, что для теста почему-то предполагается, что браузер авторизован. Так нельзя тестировать. Если нужна авторизация, то ее нужно производить непосредственно при инициализации теста.

Comment: А с технической стороны - ну хэ зэ. Мож там разные бинарники используются.

Comment: @Эникейщик, при авторизации присутствует капча, по этому было принято решение авторизоваться заранее и использовать пользовательскую папку, в которой(по идее) будет храниться авторизация, без headless так и происходит, браузер открывается уже с авторизацией, а вот с этим режимом какая-то проблема

Comment: если это свой сайт, то я бы просто отключил капчу для тестирования. Ее можно тестировать отдельно

Comment: @Эникейщик, так бы и сделал, но к сожалению, сайт не мой)

Comment: может тут что полезное есть https://coderedirect.com/questions/568734/in-python-how-do-i-make-selenium-work-headless-with-a-saved-browser-session

Answer (score 1):

В общем решением для меня стало использование куки и отказ от профиля

После авторизации сохраняем куки

```
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))
```

А после открытия нужной страницы загружаем обратно и обновляем страницу

```
driver.get(url)
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.refresh()
```

В итоге у нас сайт с авторизаций в headless режиме

Comment: Хорошее решение :)